# Aligning content in multirow

Tags: tables, boxes, minipage, multicolumn, alignment

I want to write a document, where i group two plots and the two functions corresponding to the plots together. There should be two such groups aligned next to each other. Here is a picture of what i mean by that:

[image: plots side by side]

This is already looking very similar to what i want to achieve, however i don't like the alignment in the "formula" column.

I am currently doing this with a `tabularx`-environment with frame lines (obviously) and two `minipages`. The column with the formulas looks like:

```
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\(\displaystyle s(t) = \sigma \left(t\! +\! 
  \frac{T_i}{2}\right) - \sigma\left(t - \frac{T_i}{2}\right)\) \hfill 
  \horizontaltransform[F]{} \hfill \(\displaystyle\undersl{S}(f) = T_i 
  \cdot \frac{\sin(\pi f T_i)}{\pi f T_i}\)}\\ \hline
```

(`verticaltransform` is a TikZ-macro that i have put together)

How can i improve this for the formulas to be centered to the column on top and the transformation-symbol to be centered in the column?
Is this even the way to write it or are there better alternatives? The code looks hairy and i have concerns about different height, once i proceed to other functions and their spectrum.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx, multicol, graphicx, trfsigns}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}% for vertical centering text in X column

\begin{document}

\scriptsize

\begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a} &%
                                                  \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \hfill \(\displaystyle s(t) = \sigma \left(t\! +\! \frac{T_i}{2}\right) - \sigma\left(t - \frac{T_i}{2}\right)\) \hfill \(\laplace\) \hfill \(\displaystyle\undersl{S}(f) = T_i \cdot \frac{\sin(\pi f T_i)}{\pi f T_i}\) \hfill }\\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a} &%
                                                  \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ \hfill \(\displaystyle s(t) = \sigma \left(t\! +\! \frac{T_i}{2}\right) - \sigma\left(t - \frac{T_i}{2}\right)\) \hfill \(\laplace\) \hfill \(\displaystyle\undersl{S}(f) = T_i \cdot \frac{\sin(\pi f T_i)}{\pi f T_i}\) \hfill }\\ \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could yo please edit your MWE  in order to make a) compilable (e.g. regarding missing `}`, packages...)  and b) make it reproduce the output you showed in your screenshot. Could you please also clarify the desired alignment of the formulas (sepecially regarding "centered to the column on top")?

Comment: Of course, thanks for the comment. I considered the original code to be too long for an MWE! I'm on my mobile right now, will edit it later today.

Comment: Assuming that the plots were also made in latex you could check if replacing them by `\includegraphics{example-image}` also leads to the same alignment. If so, you could use the latter in order to shorten your MWE.

Comment: I didn't know about `example-image`! Thank you! Edited MWE

Comment: your formulas are to wide (even in `\scriptsize` font size) that can be fit in width of one cell. is rotating of table to `landscape orientation acceptable to you?

Answer (score 1):

- your formulas are to wide (even in \scriptsize font size) that can be fit in width of two cells on the way as you like to have
- to overcome this, you need to enlarge the table width:

  - one way is increase text width localy by use of `\adjustwidth` macro from the `changepage`packet
  - another way is rotate table or put it into `landscape` page orientation
- in the first case, after rewriting you equations code (that it can be compiled) you can obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hhline,     % new
            makecell,   % new
            tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{trfsigns}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}% for vertical centering text in X column
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\marginparwidth}
    \scriptsize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \setcellgapes{4pt}
    \makegapedcells
\centering\medskip
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X X||X X |}
    \hhline{|--||--|}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
                &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}     \\
    \hhline{|--||--|}
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{$}c<{$}||}{
            s(t) = \sigma \left(t{+}\dfrac{T_i}{2}\right) - \sigma\left(t{-}\dfrac{T_i}{2}\right)
            \ \laplace\
            \underline{S}(f) = T_i \dfrac{\sin(\pi f T_i)}{\pi f T_i}
            \rule{4.4em}{0pt}  % manually adjusted
                                    }
            &
    \multicolumn{2}{>{$}c<{$}|}{
            s(t) = \sigma \left(t{+}\dfrac{T_i}{2}\right) - \sigma\left(t{-}\dfrac{T_i}{2}\right)
            \ \laplace\
            \underline{S}(f) = T_i \dfrac{\sin(\pi f T_i)}{\pi f T_i}
            \rule{4.4em}{0pt}  % manually adjusted
                                    }                                       \\
    \hhline{|--||--|}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
    &   \multicolumn{1}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}|}{
            s(t) = \sigma \left(t{+}\dfrac{T_i}{2}\right) - \sigma\left(t{-}\dfrac{T_i}{2}\right)
    &   \multicolumn{1}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}|}{
            \underline{S}(f) = T_i \dfrac{\sin(\pi f T_i)}{\pi f T_i}
                                               }                                \\
    \hhline{|--||--|}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

(red lines indicate page layout)

- in the second case with use of `sidewaystable˙ environment you can increase font size to ˙\footnotesize`:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{geometry}

  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{hhline,     % new
              makecell,   % new
              tabularx}
  \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
  \usepackage{trfsigns}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  %\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}% for vertical centering text in X column
  \usepackage{rotating}

  %---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
  \usepackage{showframe}
  \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
  \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%
  \usepackage{lipsum}

  \begin{document}
  \lipsum[11]

  \begin{sidewaystable}
      \footnotesize
      \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
      \setcellgapes{4pt}
      \makegapedcells
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X X||X X |}
      \hhline{|--||--|}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
          &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
              &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
                  &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}     \\
      \hhline{|--||--|}
      \multicolumn{2}{|>{$}c<{$}||}{
              s(t) = \sigma \left(t{+}\dfrac{T_i}{2}\right) - \sigma\left(t{-}\dfrac{T_i}{2}\right)
              \ \laplace\
              \underline{S}(f) = T_i \dfrac{\sin(\pi f T_i)}{\pi f T_i}
              \rule{5em}{0pt} % manually adjusted
                                      }
              &
      \multicolumn{2}{>{$}c<{$}|}{
              s(t) = \sigma \left(t{+}\dfrac{T_i}{2}\right) - \sigma\left(t{-}\dfrac{T_i}{2}\right)
              \ \laplace\
              \underline{S}(f) = T_i \dfrac{\sin(\pi f T_i)}{\pi f T_i}
              \rule{5em}{0pt} % manually adjusted
                                      }                                       \\
      \hhline{|--||--|}
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{sidewaystable}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use a unique `tabular` and a strut (`\rule[-12pt]{0pt}{30pt}`) to enlarge the row with the formulae.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx, multicol, graphicx, trfsigns}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}% for vertical centering text in X column

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\scriptsize\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a} &   \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\rule[-12pt]{0pt}{30pt}\(\displaystyle s(t) = \sigma \left(t + \frac{T_i}{2}\right) - \sigma\left(t - \frac{T_i}{2}\right)\hfill\laplace\hfill%\undersl where is this command defined?
    \underline{S}(f) = T_i \cdot \frac{\sin(\pi f T_i)}{\pi f T_i}\)}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\(\displaystyle s(t) = \sigma \left(t + \frac{T_i}{2}\right) - \sigma\left(t - \frac{T_i}{2}\right)\hfill\laplace\hfill%\undersl where is this command defined?
    \underline{S}(f) = T_i \cdot \frac{\sin(\pi f T_i)}{\pi f T_i}\) }\\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]